# Are women in Islam forced to cover themselves?

Tags: women, hijab

I am not a muslim, I just want to know more about this religion. So I have a friend who is a muslim and when she was 13 her parents told her to wear hijab (i don't know if that is how you spell it) and she did but when she turned 18 she stopped wearing it, because she didn't want to anymore. So I was wondering if in Islam the women HAVE TO cover themselves or if they only have to do it if they want to? And if they stop wearing a hijab, is that bad / are they going to be punished for it? I would love to get an answer, thank you :)

Comment: From what I know there is no punishment for not wearing it but it is better for a woman to wear it.

Answer (score 0):

In Quran e Kareem , Allah s.w.t says
يَا أَيُّهَا النَّبِيُّ قُل لِّأَزْوَاجِكَ وَبَنَاتِكَ وَنِسَاءِ الْمُؤْمِنِينَ يُدْنِينَ عَلَيْهِنَّ مِن جَلَابِيبِهِنَّ ۚ ذَٰلِكَ أَدْنَىٰ أَن يُعْرَفْنَ فَلَا يُؤْذَيْنَ ۗ وَكَانَ اللَّهُ غَفُورًا رَّحِيمًا - 33:59
O Prophet, tell your wives and your daughters and the women of the believers to bring down over themselves [part] of their outer garments. That is more suitable that they will be known and not be abused. And ever is Allah Forgiving and Merciful.

So in context of this ayah, it is better for women to cover their face partially.

Comment: Also Quran 24:30